# How To Serialize JSON Dynamically Sized Multi-dimensional Array From MongoDB

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I have some coordinates that I'm reading from a MongoDB using the 10Gen driver. The problem I'm running into is that the depth of the multi-dimensional data isn't consistent and I'm looking for a comprehensive strategy to handle the problem.

The solution must be able to write the coordinates back to MongoDB (serialize) in the same order and depth as read out (deserialized).

Two examples of different depth:

Example 1

```
     [ 
       [ [ [ 12, 33 ], [ 32, 23 ], [ 12, 32], [23, 12 ], [ 32, 32 ], [ 32, 2 ] ] ],
       [ [ [35, 12 ], [ 53, 16 ], [ 22, 54 ], [ 2, 32 ], [ 32, 32 ] ] ]
    ]
```

Deserialize into:

```
    public List<List<List<int>>> coordinates { get; set; }
```

Example 2

```
     [ 
       [ [ 2, 2 ], [120,12 ], [ 32,32 ], [ 32, 2 ], [ 3,2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 1 ] ]
     ]
```

Deserialize into:

```
public List<List<List<List<int>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
```

My initial thought was to write a custom serializer to read the data and figure out the depth, then use a wrapper method to hide the actual data from the View e.g. GetNextCoordinate() and then the function GetNextCoordinate can pull the data from the appropriate structure. That feels messy so I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Assume that the coordinates property is part of a concrete class and that the collection in MongoDB contains a mix of both types of coordinate documents. Meaning any given query to MongoDB will pull either or both type of coordinate documents and I don't know before executing the query.

Comment: I don't know what type of problem you're solving there, but this doesn't look like clean design to me. If you have lists of lists, isn't there some kind of semantic in the data? Is there no way to make sure every db object has a list of coordinates and some fields that can be used for lookup?

Comment: Agreed, however the data source is out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON
It can serialize and deserialize to lists. I don't know if it can do lists within lists.

Comment: I've already got this working by using a custom serializer that inspects the elements and determines which format is present, but it is both ugly and fragile. Hoping for a generic solution that doesn't smell so bad.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom BSON serializer/deserializer which then supports variable nested arrays.